# TSQL: datetime from character string error

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

There are some posts related to this but I'm so new to TSQL that I cannot make sense of them so please excuse me.

My procedure has:

```
    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO  dbo.myprocedure(
         Mydate

     )
     VALUES(
     CONVERT(DATETIME, @mydate, 102)
)
```

If I execute it this way:

```
EXEC mydbo.dbo.myprocedure @mydate = 'May 8 2012 9:21AM'
```

I get this error:
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

How can I solve this?

Thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), you'll see that format 102 is the ANSI format, or `yyyy.mm.dd`.  So passing a date like `2012.05.08` should work.

It looks like `2012.05.08 9:41` and `2012.05.08 9:41AM` will work too, but that's outside the documented format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
EXEC mydbo.dbo.myprocedure @mydate = '2012/05/08 09:21:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `CONVERT(DATETIME, @mydate, 102)` to `CONVERT(DATETIME, @mydate, 100)`

or just `CONVERT(DATETIME, @mydate)`

reference to [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054.aspx)
and http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/ on MSDN