# How to convert String to datetime in the SQL query?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TSQL: datetime from character string error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494528/tsql-datetime-from-character-string-error)

I am unable to convert String to datetime. I am using SQL Server 2005.

```
String frmDate="03/09/2012";
String toDate="04/09/2012";

SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date frmDate1 = formater.parse(frmDate);
Date toDate1=formater.parse(toDate);


 String query3="select * from dbo.Monthly_PFSPL "  +  
    "where Convert (datetime,Added_Date,103) "  +  
"between '"+frmDate1+"' and '"+toDate1+"' ";
        rsobj1=stat2.executeQuery(query3);
```

I am getting this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string
```

Comment: What datatype is `Added_Date`?

Comment: You should change that to `datetime` and use date parameters instead of generating your query in code.

Comment: I tried that too but there is an error while inserting into datetime Added_Date. So I am trying like this.

Comment: Thanks to all for your responses. I got the solution I finally changed Added_Date to datetime and the problem was importing java.util.Date. But now using java.sql.Date and it now solved.

Answer (score 1):

You *must* have to use PreparedStatement and parameterized SQL statement.

```
String query="select * from dbo.Monthly_PFSPL where Convert(datetime,Added_Date,103) between  ? and ?";
```